# psql copy from read data from script

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am trying to export / import a set of tables from a PostgreSQL database.

I am using psql's `copy from` with `stdin` from a script. I have read that data (formerly produced using `copy to` with `stdout`) can be read and delimited using the command escape `\.`.

What I didn't get from the documentation clearly is what would happen if `\.` appears in the formerly exported data.

Specifcally this section of the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/app-psql.html) (emphasis mine) isn't very clear about that.

> For `\copy ... from stdin`, data rows are read from the same source that
>   issued the command, **continuing until `\.`** is read or the stream reaches
>   EOF. This option is useful for populating tables in-line within a SQL
>   script file. For `\copy ... to stdout`, output is sent to the same place
>   as psql command output, and the COPY count command status is not
>   printed (since it might be confused with a data row). To read/write
>   psql's standard input or output regardless of the current command
>   source or \o option, write from pstdin or to pstdout.

Can / must a `\.` appearing in the data escaped somehow?

I am currently using `utf8` encoded `text` format for the export / import.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the relevant information in the [documentation of the SQL `COPY` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) (TEXT Format section, again emphasis mine):

> End of data can be represented by **a single line containing just backslash-period (`\.`)**. An end-of-data marker is not necessary when reading from a file, since the end of file serves perfectly well; it is needed only when copying data to or from client applications using pre-3.0 client protocol.